# Should I create an interface, class or both?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning Typescript and while I was designing the types. I got in a dilemma.

Interfaces, as I understand, give context to an object.

If it's a JSON related data that comes from a server I would probably assign to an Interface.

```js
interface PersonInterface {
  age: number;
  name: string;
}
```

But there are occasions that I want to execute functions related to this JSON data. Then a class would be more appropriate.

```js
class Person {
  age: number;
  name: string;
  constructor(body: PersonInterface){
     this.age = body.age;
     this.name = body.name;
  }

  getBirthDate(){
     return new Date().getFullYear() - this.age;
  }
}
```

I'm aware that Interfaces are not compiled, so the source code output is smaller, but I might need the classes.

My dilemma is there are situations that I don't need a class, just static types. And there are occasions that a class would be handy. If I want to have both, one for normal objects and other for instances, I would need to keep always changing the `Interface` types and the `Class` attributes.

What is the best practice for this situation?

Comment: "If I want to have both, one for normal objects and other for instances, I would need to keep always changing the Interface types and the Class attributes." This part is a little confusing because this shouldn't be the case. Why wouldn't `Person` just be an `IPerson`?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Maybe I'm just being picky... Let's say I just want to type check on raw JSON data. If I use `Person` that means the JSON data is a instance of the Class, which is not.

Comment: You'll probably want your class to implement the interface.

Comment: As you seem to be aware of the pitfalls and trafeoffs, this simply becomes a somewhat subjective design question. Everyone is going to have a different opinion. My advice would be to use an `interface` to represent the JSON and, rather than creating a wrapper class to add functionality to it, I would put that logic in freestanding functions or service classes that operate on the `interface`. Separation of concerns